# MySQL Loop from two different Tables

Tags: php, mysql, union

i want to get values from two different tables. 
my problem is the table have no relation to each other but the "team_id"

i have a "player" and a "player_stat" table.

### my result should look like:

Playername (from the "player" table) 
Points: 8, Assists: 2, Fouls: 0 (from the "player_stat" table)

Playername 2 (from the "player" table) 
Points: 8, Assists: 2, Fouls: 0 (from the "player_stat" table)

---

Here is my try:

```
<?php 
/* PLAYERSTAT */
$attrs = array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT data.player_stat
    FROM 
    (SELECT * from player_stat
    UNION
    SELECT * from player) data                              
");
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>  
echo $row["playername"]."<br>";
echo $row["points"]." ".$row["assists"];
<?php  }
?>
```

my tables

player:
id 
team_id
name
created

player_stat:
id 
team_id
points
assists
fouls
created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SQL query could look like this (supposed the team_id is supposed to connect the stats and the player):

```
SELECT
 player.playername,
 player_stat.points,
 player_stat.assists,
 player_stat.fouls
FROM
 player
 LEFT JOIN player_stat ON (player.team_id = player_stat.team_id)
```

But it's a little bit strange, that the only relation between your tables is the team_id. If the output should be per player you have to introduce the relation between the stats and the player.

Say, your player can be in a team, there should be a team_id and a player_id. And your `JOIN` would then read:

```
LEFT JOIN player_stats ON (player.player_id = player_stats.player_id)
```

and as addition you can query for your team:

```
WHERE
 player.team_id = 55
```

or you can add other joins so that you get your team details and so on.

Comment: Where's the correlation between the players ?!? team_id doesn't mean you can match player bio with player stats.

Comment: that was also my thought... but as the OP said, it's the only relation between the tables so far

Comment: True, however to answer his question I would way he can't get the desired output with what he has at the moment ... I would say that he needs to implement some sort of correlation between player and stats

Comment: the problem is that the player_stat table is empty at first but i already want to show up the all the players from player. the player_stat table gets filled when the user click a submit to add points, fouls etc..

Comment: @paul ... how do you know which stats belong to which player ?!?

Comment: @paul, just inverse the join (i.e. if you have the players first, make a left join to player_stat) -> if they are empty you'll get empty stats for the playername

Comment: @RaphaelMüller i get no result if i inverse the join.

Comment: @paul, if you just use `SELECT player.playername FROM player` you'll get the playernames. then if you add the join and the corresponding rows for player_stat you should get the playernames with the results that match (i.e. empty ones for empty stats)

Comment: @RaphaelMüller all right that worked. thank you a lot! :) but now i i.e. count the points up for a player in game one. he counts it up always so in game one he makes i.e. 40 points and then in game two the points are still at 40 and not 0. so how do i can distinguish between the two gamestats?

Comment: @paul, do you have the stats separated in the table? if so, you can use `SUM(player_stat.points)` in conjunction with `GROUP BY player_stat.team_id` or whatever

Comment: @RaphaelMüller yes, the stats are in a separated table. but how can i combine the "sum" and "group by" method with the query above? is that possible?

Comment: @paul, use it as you would do it logical: `SELECT player.playername, SUM(player_stat.points), ... FROM player JOIN ... WHERE ... GROUP BY player_stat.team_id` have a look at the examples at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 3):

Modify your select statement to read:

```
SELECT * FROM player, player_stat WHERE player.team_id = player_stat.team_id
```

The above is based on your statement that they have the team_id in common. If this is not what you are trying to achieve please refine your question and post the database schema.